# CSS Hover Not Centering

Tags: html, css

I am creating a div which will enclose a users name and when they hover over a profile image then it will display the name over the image, when I am doing this it does not center the div over the image solely which will be causing a problem when styling the website.

My CSS is below:

```
.miniProfileImage {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px dashed #28A745;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;    
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.img-container:hover .miniProfileImage {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.img-container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.middleText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

A sample HTML mark-up can be seen here:

```
<div class='img-container'>               
  <img class='miniProfileImage' src='http://via.placeholder.com/500x500'>
  <div class='middle'>
    <p class='middleText'>Some Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also created a JS Fiddle to represent what is happening

```css
.miniProfileImage {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px dashed #28A745;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;    
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.img-container:hover .miniProfileImage {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.img-container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.middleText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-container'>               
  <img class='miniProfileImage' src='http://via.placeholder.com/500x500'>
  <div class='middle'>
    <p class='middleText'>Some Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `.img-container {background-color:red}` and you'll see that your text is in fact in the middle of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your surrounding `<div class='img-container'>` has a width that is wider than the image.

If you want the div to have the same size as the image, you can do the following:

```
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.miniProfileImage {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px dashed #28A745;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;    
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-container:hover .miniProfileImage {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.img-container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.middleText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-container'>               
  <img class='miniProfileImage' src='http://via.placeholder.com/500x500'>
  <div class='middle'>
    <p class='middleText'>Some Name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please correct the CSS like this

```
.img-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 210px;
    }
```

and `.middle {white-space:nowrap}` you can give `.miniProfileImage {max-width:100%}` to image